# How to configure web driver codeception in yii2 with selenium

Tags: selenium, yii2, webdriver, automated-tests, codeception

I'm so confusing with this problem. So anyone who has taken the same trouble like this, please kindly inform me.

```
 [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException]
  Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
  Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03
  :16'
  System info: host: 'DESKTOP-KLV8HD0', ip: '192.168.2.168', os.name: 'Window
  s 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
  Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

How to resolve ? Here is the description of application that I used:

1. Google Chrome (62.0.3202.75) -> Updated new version for now
2. Chrome Driver (2.9) -> Updated by http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html (I thought 2.9 version is newer version)
3. selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1

Comment: The problem is solved. My Chrome Driver is not updated. So I just downloaded the newer version (2.33 for now) and it works !

Comment: Please mark your question as closed.

Comment: You might want to update selenium too, 2.47 is more then 2 years old. The newest version is 3.7